# Сериализация формы с групповыми полями

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно передать поля формы get параметром, при этом группы полей например:

```
<input name="test" value="1">
<input name="test" value="2"/>
<input name="test" value="3"/>
```

должны передаваться в виде site.ru?test=1,2,3

Сам сделал, но мне кажется, что есть решение получше. 
Делаю так:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    "use strict";
    const result = {};
    const extend = function (i, element) {
        const node = result[element.name];
        if ('undefined' !== typeof node && node !== null) {
            if ($.isArray(node)) {
                node.push(element.value);
            } else {
                result[element.name] = [node, element.value];
            }
        } else {
            result[element.name] = element.value;
        }
    };

    $.each(this.serializeArray(), extend);
    return result;
};
```

и

```
$('body').on('change','.filter', function () {
        const params = $('.filters').serializeObject();
        const urlParams = {};
        $.each(params, function(id) {
            ret = $('input[name^="'+id+'"]:checked').map(function() {
                return this.value;
            }).get().join(',');
            urlParams[id] = ret;
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: document.location.href,
            data: urlParams,
            success: function(data){
                $(".product-content").html($(data).find('.product-list'));
            }
        });
    });
```

Так-же этот вариант не совсем подходит так как мне нужно менять url через   `window.history.replaceState`

И если я делаю

```
success: function(data){
                $(".product-content").html($(data).find('.product-list'));
                window.history.replaceState({},'',this.url)
            }
```

Параметры каждый раз добавляются к url-у...

Answer (score 0):

Решение сделал:
Сериализуем форму в объект:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    "use strict";
    const result = {};
    const extend = function (i, element) {
        const node = result[element.name];
        if ('undefined' !== typeof node && node !== null) {
            if ($.isArray(node)) {
                node.push(element.value);
            } else {
                result[element.name] = [node, element.value];
            }
        } else {
            result[element.name] = element.value;
        }
    };

    $.each(this.serializeArray(), extend);
    return result;
};
```

Выполняем по изменению нужного элемента:

```
$('body').on('change','.filter', function () {
    const params = $('.filters').serializeObject();
    let currentKey;
    if(isEmpty(params)){
        updateQueryStringParam($(this).prop('name'), $(this).val(), true);
    }else{
        currentKey = $(this).prop('name');
        if($('input[name^="'+currentKey+'"]:checked').length === 0){
            updateQueryStringParam($(this).prop('name'), $(this).val(), true);
        }else {
            $.each(params, function (id, val) {
                let value;
                if ($.isArray(val)) {
                    value = val.join(',');
                } else {
                    value = val;
                }
                updateQueryStringParam(id, value);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Метод получения url с нужными параметрами не удаляя текущие и удаляя те, которых нет:

```
     function updateQueryStringParam(param, value, remove = false) {
    const baseUrl = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('');
    const urlQueryString = document.location.search;
    let newParam = param + '=' + value,
        params = '?' + newParam;
    if (urlQueryString) {
        const keyRegex = new RegExp('([\?&])' + param + '[^&]*');
        if (urlQueryString.match(keyRegex) !== null) {
            params = urlQueryString.replace(keyRegex, remove ? '' : "$1" + newParam);
        } else {
            params = urlQueryString + '&' + newParam;
        }
    }
    if(params.indexOf('?') === -1 ){
        params = params.replace('&','?');
        console.log(params);
    }
    window.history.replaceState({}, "", baseUrl + params);
    return baseUrl + params;
}
```

Проверка объекта на empty:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
            for(const key in obj) {
                if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Если кто-то предложит более изящное решение - буду рад)